# iPhone :Change Application Name and icon

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, rename

I am new to iPhone programming.
I created an application in Xcode. I want to change the application name and icon. However I can change the application name (which is appeared below the icon of application in iPhone) and icon from plist.
I want to ask that whether there are any other method or trick which i can use to change the icon and application name.

My project requirement is that end user want to change application name and icon frequently

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is absolutely no way for the end user to change the application name or icon of applicaitons distributed via the App Store. I believe it would be possible to do this on jailbroken phones, but I'm not an expert in that area.

Comment: ok. if i want to change the application icon and name in jail broken phones then what is the steps i follow. Please suggest

Comment: As I mentioned before, I'm not an expert in the area of jailbroken phone apps. I'm not exactly certain on the amount of security provided by the SDK to create jailbroken apps or the access to files that it allows you. If you were to implement this, it would never be able to be distributed to the app store, and would be very difficult and messy to implement (as it would involve writing directly to files stored outside your applications own directory). Perhaps ask another question which is more specific to this need? I'm sure there's some good iPhone devs around on this site, Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Jay is correct. You need to specify an icon and name for your app in the info.plist file. Those values can't be changed dynamically. If you want to change the name or the icon, you would need to fix them in xcode and submit an update to Apple for approval.

__mike

Answer (score 0):

I disagree with the above answers.
Please go take a look at the free app on Itune,  "OneTap" (or "onetap")
you will see that you can create a dynamicly new app with your own icon image.

Answer (score -1):

There's definitely an app in cydia to accomplish this but you must jailbreak your iPhone or iPod touch